Modeling Point Processes with Covariates: Use of quadscheme in R
I am currently attempting to model fire outbreaks using precipitation as a covariate. Upon reading various suggestions, I came across the quadscheme function in R. According to the documentation, the function is defined as follows:
quadscheme(data, dummy, method="grid", ...)
data - The observed data point pattern. An object of class ppp. This part is clear to me.
dummy - The pattern of dummy points for the quadrature. An object of class ppp or in a format recognized by as.ppp(). Defaults to default.dummy(data, ...). Here is where I encounter difficulties. How do I incorporate precipitation?
...
Here is the example of what I tried
fire_outbreaks <- data.frame(
  x = runif(100, min = 0, max = 100),
  y = runif(100, min = 0, max = 100)
)

precipitation <- data.frame(
  x = runif(40, min = 0, max = 100),
  y = runif(40, min = 0, max = 100),
  precip_mm = runif(40, min = 0, max = 4)
)

fire_outbreaks.ppp <- ppp(fire_outbreaks$x, fire_outbreaks$y, owin(c(0, 100), c(0, 100)))

quadscheme <- quadscheme(data=fire_outbreaks.ppp, dummy=list(x=precipitation$x, y=precipitation$y))

Cov <- data.frame(precipitation[, 3])

ppm(quadscheme, ~precipitation$precip_mm, Poisson(), covariates=Cov)


Error in mpl.get.covariates(covariates, P, Pname, covfunargs) :  Number of rows in ‘covariates’ does not equal the number of quadrature points
Could you please provide guidance on how to correctly incorporate precipitation data as a covariate in the quadscheme function?
Thank you for your assistance.
Best regards,
Alex Monito Nhancololo

It appears you are starting from scratch with parametric modelling in spatstat. I highly recommend that you have a look at Chapter 9 of Spatial Point Patterns: Methodology and Applications with R which you can download as a free sample chapter at http://book.spatstat.org/ (disclaimer: I’m a co-author of the book)
Briefly, if you want to model how the likelihood of observing a fire outbreak is depending on the amount of precipitation a given location has received you need to know the value of precipitation both where fires did break out and some places where fire didn’t break out.
The dummy points have the role of locations where fire didn’t break out, so you need to know the amount of precipitation both at the data and dummy points.
Ideally you have precipitation data on a fine grid over the entire observation region (window), and you simply use the value at the nearest grid point as the precipitation value for each of the data/dummy points.
You have precipitation values at very non-systematic locations, and one option would be to do spatial smoothing to obtain precipitation values at any location in the observation window.
Normally, you would not specify the quadscheme manually but it will be created “under the hood” by the function ppm().
Manual construction is mainly relevant if you also had precipitation values for the data point and some background dummy points as in the following example adapted from your example:
library(spatstat)
set.seed(42)
fire_outbreaks <- data.frame(
  x = runif(100, min = 0, max = 100),
  y = runif(100, min = 0, max = 100)
)

precipitation <- data.frame(
  x = runif(40, min = 0, max = 100),
  y = runif(40, min = 0, max = 100),
  precip_mm = runif(40, min = 0, max = 4)
)

fire_outbreaks.ppp <- ppp(fire_outbreaks$x, fire_outbreaks$y, owin(c(0, 100), c(0, 100)))

precipitation_at_outbreaks <- data.frame(
  x = fire_outbreaks$x,
  y = fire_outbreaks$y,
  precip_mm = runif(100, min = 0, max = 1)
)

quadscheme <- quadscheme(data=fire_outbreaks.ppp, dummy=list(x=precipitation$x, y=precipitation$y))

Cov <- rbind(precipitation_at_outbreaks, precipitation)[, "precip_mm", drop=FALSE]
dim(Cov)
#> [1] 140   1

head(Cov)
#>   precip_mm
#> 1 0.4303332
#> 2 0.3937769
#> 3 0.1419089
#> 4 0.2798067
#> 5 0.5648222
#> 6 0.9351395


ppm(quadscheme ~ precip_mm, Poisson(), covariates=Cov)
#> Nonstationary Poisson process
#> Fitted to point pattern dataset 'quadscheme'
#> 
#> Log intensity:  ~precip_mm
#> 
#> Fitted trend coefficients:
#> (Intercept)   precip_mm 
#>  -4.1118527  -0.8219116 
#> 
#>               Estimate      S.E.   CI95.lo    CI95.hi Ztest       Zval
#> (Intercept) -4.1118527 0.1494498 -4.404769 -3.8189364   *** -27.513262
#> precip_mm   -0.8219116 0.2307265 -1.274127 -0.3696959   ***  -3.562276

A more typical scenario is that you have precipitation data on a fine grid over the entire observation region (window), and we can emulate this by smoothing out the irregularly observed values using Smooth().
First a plot of the irregular precipitation data:
precipitation_ppp <- as.ppp(precipitation, W = owin(c(0,100),c(0,100)) )
colfun <- spatstat.options("image.colfun")
colmap <- colourmap(colfun(100), range = c(0, 4))
symmap <- symbolmap(cols=colmap, size = 2, pch = 19, range = c(0,4))
plot(precipitation_ppp, symap = symmap, main = "Precipitation at locations", legend = FALSE)
plot(colmap, add = TRUE, xlim = c(103, 108), ylim = c(20, 80), vertical = TRUE)


Now we smooth the precipitation data and plot them with the same colour map as above:
precip_mm <- Smooth(precipitation_ppp, sigma = 10)
plot(precip_mm, cols = colmap, main = "Smoothed precipitation")


Now we can use the smoothed precipitation values as covariates in the model:
ppm(fire_outbreaks.ppp ~ precip_mm, Poisson())
#> Nonstationary Poisson process
#> Fitted to point pattern dataset 'fire_outbreaks.ppp'
#> 
#> Log intensity:  ~precip_mm
#> 
#> Fitted trend coefficients:
#> (Intercept)   precip_mm 
#>  -4.4080927  -0.1207705 
#> 
#>               Estimate      S.E.    CI95.lo    CI95.hi Ztest        Zval
#> (Intercept) -4.4080927 0.2580664 -4.9138936 -3.9022917   *** -17.0812318
#> precip_mm   -0.1207705 0.1482876 -0.4114088  0.1698678        -0.8144347

